# How to replace specific words in string using java?

Tags: java, string

I have this string variable:

```
String a = "malam mingguan bareng geng motor kepominfo kemkominfo bem rema upi";
```

What I want to do is replace "malam mingguan" to "malam-mingguan". And the output will be like this:

```
String a = "malam-mingguan bareng geng motor kepominfo kemkominfo bem rema upi";
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `String.replaceAll`, search StackOverflow, u will get numerous examples.

Comment: @blackSmith: `replace()` is much better than `replaceAll()` here.

Comment: @Keppil : My mistake. Thanks for pointing out. This question most probably be a duplicate.

Comment: @blackSmith: Yeah, I am searching for a good one. A lot of them have bad answer it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
a = a.replace("malam mingguan", "malam-mingguan");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use replaceAll function.

Code:

```
String a = "malam mingguan bareng geng motor kepominfo kemkominfo bem rema upi";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("(?<=malam)\\s(?=mingguan)", "-"));
```

Output:

```
malam-mingguan bareng geng motor kepominfo kemkominfo bem rema upi
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't do exactly what OP is asking for even if the result is the same in this case. It is also overly complicated. A simple `replace()` is definitely the better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `replaceAll` with a regex like `malam\s+mingguan`:

```
a.replaceAll("malam\\s+mingguan", "malam-mingguan");
```